# Influence of forking on existing mysql-connection

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a server which is/should be able to handle a lot of connections at the same time.
Now sometimes I have an error: “Lost connection to MySQL server during query”. At the time I am fixing this with

```
def mysql_handling(string):
    global cursor
    tries=0
    while True:
        if tries<5:
            try: 
                cursor.execute(string)
                if 'SELECT' not in string:
                    db.commit()
                break
            except MySQLdb.Error, e:
                print("Error %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
                cursor.close() 
                time.sleep(0.1)
                cursor = get_cursor() #setting up a new mysql connection
                #mysql_error_tracking(string)
                tries+=1
        else:
            sys.exit(1)
```

So now I am able to handle a lot of connections at the same time, but at the times that I have this error (Lost conn.) I want to know at which query this happens, and if there is somekind of pattern in this. So to track this, I also want to store this in the mysql-database with a script somewhat like this:

```
def mysql_error_tracking(string):
    #Clone/fork
    try:
        error_serv = os.fork()
    except:
        print "error_FORK failed!"

    if error_serv:
        print 'there is a MYSQL-ERROR, SAVE!!!'

        cursor.execute("SELECT count FROM query_errors WHERE string= "+"'"+str(string)+"'")
        data=cursor.fetchone()
        print data
        if data is None:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO query_errors (string) VALUES ("+"'"+str(string)+"')")
            db.commit()
            print 'insert in queries'
        else:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE query_errors SET count=count+1 WHERE string= "+"'"+str(string)+"'")
            db.commit()
            print 'count ploes 1'
        sys.exit(0)
```

This does work, but **forking** the connection seems to really pressurize the already existing mysql-connection, is it better to just not-fork instead?

Comment: I would suggest not to log db errors into db :) Better to log it to some local file, via syslog or webserver's error log.

Comment: @Marki555 I will probably do this. Thank you